# Node.js Socket.io - Server setInterval running at half speed, full speed only when socket.on is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My server is acting weird -- the updating `setInterval` under `Update LOBBIES` is set to run @ 1000/60ms or 60cps, which I'm only getting a steady 34cps. But when `socket.emit('angle')` is used from `CLIENT` side, it runs smoothly at 60cps up until `socket.emit('angle')` stops, then returns back to 34cps. It's been 3 days and I still have absolutely no idea. Code doesn't seem to have a throttle issue, and weirdly enough, works better when a `socket.on` event is called for the `angle` only, not others. Doesn't make any sense! Any ideas?

**HTML/Javascript Client**

```
User.onConnect = (socket) => {  
    var lobbies = [];
    socket.on('updateLobbies', (data) => {
        $('#menu-screen-navigation-display-play ul').empty();
        $('#menu-screen-navigation-display-play ul').append(
            "<li style='position: fixed;top: calc(13vh); width: 47.5%; height: calc(5vh); left:26.25%;background-color: rgba(50,50,50,1);'>" +
            "   <table>" +
            "       <th style='width:10%'>" +
            "           <span></span>" +
            "       </th>" +
            "       <th style='width:20%'>" +
            "           <span class='play-lobby'>Lobby</span>" +
            "       </th>" +
            "       <th style='width:20%'>" +
            "           <span class='play-map'>Map</span>" +
            "       </th>" +
            "       <th style='width:20%'>" +
            "           <span class='play-gamemode'>Game Mode</span>" +
            "       </th>" +
            "       <th style='width:15%'>" +
            "           <span class='play-players'>Players</span>" +
            "       </th>" +
            "       <th style='width:15%'>" +
            "           <span></span>" +
            "       </th>" +
            "   </table>" +
            "</li>");
        $('#menu-screen-navigation-display-play ul').append(
            "<li style='position: fixed;bottom: calc(4vh); width: 47.5%; height: calc(5vh); left:26.25%;background-color: rgba(50,50,50,1);'>" +
            "   <table>" +
            "       <th style='width:10%'>" +
            "           <span></span>" +
            "       </th>" +
            "       <th style='width:20%'>" +
            "           <span class='play-lobby'></span>" +
            "       </th>" +
            "       <th style='width:20%'>" +
            "           <span class='play-map'></span>" +
            "       </th>" +
            "       <th style='width:20%'>" +
            "           <span class='play-gamemode'></span>" +
            "       </th>" +
            "       <th style='width:15%'>" +
            "           <span class='play-players'></span>" +
            "       </th>" +
            "       <th style='width:15%'>" +
            "           <span></span>" +
            "       </th>" +
            "   </table>" +
            "</li>");
        for(let i in data){
            lobbies[i] = data[i];
            
            switch(lobbies[i].mode){
                case 'Outbreak': {
                    lobbies[i].modeColor = 'green';
                    
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    lobbies[i].modeColor = 'white';
                }
            }           
            switch(lobbies[i].map){
                case 'Urban Delight': {
                    lobbies[i].mapSrc = 'img/ui/map-icons/urbanDelight.png';
                    
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            $('#menu-screen-navigation-display-play ul').append(
                "<li>" +
                "   <table>" +
                "       <th style='width:10%'>" +
                "           <img src='" + lobbies[i].mapSrc + "'/>" +
                "       </th>" +
                "       <th style='width:20%'>" +
                "           <span class='play-lobby'>" + lobbies[i].title + "</span>" +
                "       </th>" +
                "       <th style='width:20%'>" +
                "           <span class='play-map'>" + lobbies[i].map + "</span>" +
                "       </th>" +
                "       <th style='width:20%'>" +
                "           <span class='play-gamemode' style='color:"+lobbies[i].modeColor+"'>" + lobbies[i].mode + "</span>" +
                "       </th>" +
                "       <th style='width:15%'>" +
                "           <span class='play-players'>" + lobbies[i].online + " / " + lobbies[i].max + "</span>" +
                "       </th>" +
                "       <th style='width:15%'>" +
                "           <button id='"+ lobbies[i].title + "' class='bubble'>Join</button>" +
                "       </th>" +
                "   </table>" +
                "</li>");
                
            $('#'+lobbies[i].title).click(function(){
                playAudio(SFX['pop']);
                socket.emit('lobby.join', this.id);
                $('#menu-screen').hide();
                $('#menu-canvas').hide();
                $('#game-screen').show();
                MUSIC['menu'].pause();
                MUSIC['menu'].currentTime = 0;
                
                game(socket);
            });
        }
    });
    socket.on('gameID', (data) => {
        MAIN.id = data;
    });
    socket.on('sendClientChat', (data) => {
        if(data.user == 'server'){
            $("#chat-list").append(`<li><span class="chat-message" style="color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);"> ${data.msg}</span></li>`);
        }
        else {
            $("#chat-list").append(`<li><span class="chat-message"><span style="color:red;">${data.user}:</span> ${chatFilter(data.msg)}</span></li>`);
        }
        $("#chat-list").scrollTop($("#chat-list").prop('scrollHeight'));
    });
    socket.on('lobbyinfo', (data) => {
        MAP = data;
    });
    socket.on('refresh', (data) => {
        PLAYER_LIST = data.players;
        for(var P in PLAYER_LIST){
            if(MAIN.id == PLAYER_LIST[P].id){
                MAIN.position = PLAYER_LIST[P].position;
                break;
            }
        }
        $('#serverCPS').text(data.server.cps);
    });
}



var controlReady = {
    up:         true,
    down:       true,
    left:       true,
    right:      true,
    Q:          true,
    E:          true,
    R:          true,
    SHIFT:      true,
    SPACE:      true,
    ENTER:      true,
    click:      true
};
function controls(mobile, socket){  
    if(mobile){
        $('#touchable-screen').show();
        document.getElementById("touchable-screen").addEventListener("touchstart", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            
            emitMouseClick(true);
            emitMouseAngle(socket, event.touches[0]);
        });
        document.getElementById("touchable-screen").addEventListener("touchmove", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            
            emitMouseAngle(socket, event.touches[0]);
        });
        document.getElementById("touchable-screen").addEventListener("touchend", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            
            emitMouseClick(false);
            emitMouseAngle(socket, event.touches[0]);
        });
        
        var joystickRadius  = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 5);
        
        document.getElementById("joystick-left").style.width    = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 30) +"px";
        document.getElementById("joystick-left").style.height   = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 30) +"px";
        document.getElementById("joystick-left").style.left     = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 3) +"px";
        document.getElementById("joystick-left").style.bottom   = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 3) +"px";
        
        document.getElementById("joystick-left-stick").style.width  = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 20) +"px";
        document.getElementById("joystick-left-stick").style.height     = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 20) +"px";
        document.getElementById("joystick-left-stick").style.right  = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 5) +"px";
        document.getElementById("joystick-left-stick").style.bottom     = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 2.5) +"px";
        
        let myStickLeft = new JoystickController("joystick-left-stick", joystickRadius, 8);
        
        document.getElementById("joystick-right").style.width   = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 30) +"px";
        document.getElementById("joystick-right").style.height  = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 30) +"px";
        document.getElementById("joystick-right").style.right   = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 3) +"px";
        document.getElementById("joystick-right").style.bottom  = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 3) +"px";
        
        document.getElementById("joystick-right-stick").style.width     = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 20) +"px";
        document.getElementById("joystick-right-stick").style.height    = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 20) +"px";
        document.getElementById("joystick-right-stick").style.right     = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 5) +"px";
        document.getElementById("joystick-right-stick").style.bottom    = Math.round(window.innerHeight/100 * 2.5) +"px";
        
        let myStickRight = new JoystickController("joystick-right-stick", joystickRadius, 8);
        
        $('#joystick-left').show();
        $('#joystick-right').show();
        $('#chat-input').hide();
    }
    else{
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
            emitMouseAngle(socket, event);
        });
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
            emitMouseAngle(socket, event);
            emitMouseClick(true);
        });
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
            emitMouseAngle(socket, event);
            emitMouseClick(false);
        });
    }
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if(controlReady.up && (event.keyCode === 87 || event.keyCode == 38)){//UP
            controlReady.up = false;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'up',state:true});
        }
        if(controlReady.down && (event.keyCode == 83 || event.keyCode == 40)){//DOWN
            controlReady.down = false;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'down',state:true});
        }
        if(controlReady.left && (event.keyCode == 65 || event.keyCode == 37)){//LEFT
            controlReady.left = false;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'left',state:true});
        }
        if(controlReady.right && (event.keyCode == 68 || event.keyCode == 39)){//RIGHT
            controlReady.right = false;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'right',state:true});
        }
        
        if(controlReady.Q && event.keyCode == 81){//Q
            controlReady.Q = false;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'Q',state:true});
        }
        if(controlReady.E && event.keyCode == 69){//E
            controlReady.E = false;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'E',state:true});
        }
        if(controlReady.R && event.keyCode == 82){//R
            controlReady.R = false;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'R',state:true});
        }               
        if(controlReady.SHIFT && event.keyCode == 16){//SHIFT
            controlReady.SHIFT = false;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'shift',state:true});
        }
        if(controlReady.SPACE && event.keyCode == 32){//SPACE
            controlReady.SPACE = false;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'space',state:true});
        }
    });
    document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
        if(!controlReady.up && (event.keyCode === 87 || event.keyCode == 38)){//UP
            controlReady.up = true;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'up',state:false});
        }
        if(!controlReady.down && (event.keyCode == 83 || event.keyCode == 40)){//DOWN
            controlReady.down = true;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'down',state:false});
        }
        if(!controlReady.left && (event.keyCode == 65 || event.keyCode == 37)){//LEFT
            controlReady.left = true;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'left',state:false});
        }
        if(!controlReady.right && (event.keyCode == 68 || event.keyCode == 39)){//RIGHT
            controlReady.right = true;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'right',state:false});
        }
        
        if(!controlReady.Q && event.keyCode == 81){//Q
            controlReady.Q = true;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'Q',state:false});
        }
        if(!controlReady.E && event.keyCode == 69){//E
            controlReady.E = true;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'E',state:false});
        }
        if(!controlReady.R && event.keyCode == 82){//R
            controlReady.R = true;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'R',state:false});
        }               
        if(!controlReady.SHIFT && event.keyCode == 16){//false
            controlReady.SHIFT = true;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'shift',state:false});
        }
        if(!controlReady.SPACE && event.keyCode == 32){//SPACE
            controlReady.SPACE = true;
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'space',state:false});
        }
    });
    
    
    $('#chat-input').focus(() => {
        controlReady.ENTER = false;
    });
    $('#chat-input').blur(() => {
        controlReady.ENTER = true;
    });
    function emitMouseAngle(socket, event) {
        var mouse;
        if(settings.mobile){
            mouse = {
                x: Math.round(event.clientX * pixelDensityRatio),
                y: Math.round(event.clientY * pixelDensityRatio)
            };
        }
        else {
            mouse = {
                x: Math.round(event.x * pixelDensityRatio),
                y: Math.round(event.y * pixelDensityRatio)
            };
        };
        var angle = Math.floor(Math.atan2(mouse.y - center.y, mouse.x - center.x) * 100)/100;
        socket.emit('angle', angle);
    }
    function emitMouseClick(click){
        if(click){
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'click',state:true});
        }
        else{
            socket.emit('controls',{inputId:'click',state:false});
        }
    }
}
```

**Node.js Server Code w/ Redis**

```
const os            = require('os'),
      cluster       = require('cluster'),
      cores         = os.cpus();
var clusterCount = 0;

process.on('uncaughtException', function (exception) {
  console.log(exception); // to see your exception details in the console
  // if you are on production, maybe you can send the exception details to your
  // email as well ?
});

if(cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);    
    // Fork workers
    for (let i = 0; i < cores.length; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    });
}
else{
    const http          = require('http'),
          express       = require('express'),
          socketio      = require('socket.io'),
          process       = require('process'),
          config        = require('./config.js'),
          socketioRedis = require('socket.io-redis'),
          redis         = require('./redis.js');
    
    const settings = {
        cps: 60
    };
    
    var LOBBY_LIST = {};
    
    redis.subscriber.on('connect', () => {
        console.log(`worker ${process.pid} connected to redis(subscriber)`);
        
        redis.subscriber.subscribe('LOBBIES');
        
        redis.subscriber.on('message', (channel, data) => {
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
            switch(channel){
                case 'LOBBIES': {
                    //console.log(`Lobby -- ${parsedData.title} | ${parsedData.map} | ${parsedData.mode} | ${parsedData.max}`);
                    LOBBY_LIST[parsedData.title] = parsedData;
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        redis.subscriber.on('users', (channel, data) => {
            console.log(`${data.id} connected to worker ${data.server}`);
        });
    });
    redis.publisher.on('connect', () => {
        console.log(`worker ${process.pid} connected to redis(publisher)`);
        
        var cpu = cores[clusterCount];
        var app = express();
        var port = process.env.PORT || process.argv[2] || 8080;
        var server = app.listen(port);
        var io = socketio(server);
        var User = {};
        var SOCKET_LIST = {};
        var PLAYER_LIST = {};
        
        io.adapter(socketioRedis({host: config.redis_host, port: config.redis_port}));
        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            User.onConnect(socket);
        });
        User.onConnect = (socket) => {
            console.log(`${socket.id} connected to worker ${process.pid}`);
            var id = socket.id;
            var player = new Player(id);
            
            SOCKET_LIST[id] = socket;
            SOCKET_LIST[id].spamGuard = 0;
            
            var updateLobbies = setInterval(() => {
                socket.emit('updateLobbies', LOBBY_LIST);
            }, 3000);
            
            socket.emit('gameID', id);
            
            socket.on('serverPing', (ping) => {
                socket.emit('serverPong', ping);
            });
            socket.on('sendServerChat', (data) => {
                if(data != ' ' && data != '  ' && data != '   '){
                    if(SOCKET_LIST[socket.id].spamGuard < 3){
                        if(data.length < 100){
                            var chat = {
                                user: socket.id,
                                msg: data
                            };
                            io.sockets.emit('sendClientChat', chat);
                            SOCKET_LIST[socket.id].spamGuard++;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        var chat = {
                            user: 'server',
                            msg: 'You\'re sending messages too fast!'
                        };
                        socket.emit('sendClientChat', chat);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    var chat = {
                        user: 'server',
                        msg: 'Can\'t send an empty message!'
                    };
                    socket.emit('sendClientChat', chat);
                }
            });
            socket.on('lobby.join', (lobby) => {
                var user = {
                    id: socket.id,
                    lobby: lobby
                };
                redis.publisher.publish('JOINROOM', JSON.stringify(user));
                
                socket.emit('lobbyinfo', map[LOBBY_LIST[lobby].map]);
            });
            socket.on('lobby.leave', () => {
                var user = {
                    id: socket.id,
                    lobby: lobby
                };
                redis.publisher.publish('LEAVEROOM', JSON.stringify(user));
            });
            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                User.onDisconnect(socket);
            });
            socket.on('controls', (data) => {
                if(data.inputId === 'up'){//UP
                    player.controls.pressingUp = data.state;
                }
                else if(data.inputId === 'down'){//DOWN
                    player.controls.pressingDown = data.state;
                }
                else if(data.inputId === 'left'){//LEFT
                    player.controls.pressingLeft = data.state;
                }
                else if(data.inputId === 'right'){//RIGHT
                    player.controls.pressingRight = data.state;
                }
                else if(data.inputId === 'Q'){//Q
                    player.controls.pressingQ = data.state;
                }
                else if(data.inputId === 'E'){//E
                    player.controls.pressingE = data.state;
                }
                else if(data.inputId === 'R'){//R
                    player.controls.pressingR = data.state;
                }
                else if(data.inputId === 'shift'){//SHIFT
                    player.controls.pressingSHIFT = data.state;
                }
                else if(data.inputId === 'space'){//SPACE
                    player.controls.pressingSPACE = data.state;
                }
                
                if(data.inputId === 'click'){//Click
                    player.controls.leftClick = data.state;
                }
            });
            socket.on('angle', (data) => {
                player.angle = data;
            });
        };
        User.onDisconnect = (socket) => {
            console.log(`${socket.id} disconnected from worker ${process.pid}`);
            delete SOCKET_LIST[socket.id];
            delete PLAYER_LIST[socket.id];
            socket.disconnect();
        };
        
        var Player = function(id){
            var self = {
                id: id,
                username: 'player',
                server: '',
                position: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                },
                speed: 500,
                angle: degrees_to_radians(Math.floor(Math.random()*360)),
                controls: {
                    leftClick:      false,
                    pressingUp:     false,
                    pressingDown:   false,
                    pressingLeft:   false,
                    pressingRight:  false,
                    pressingQ:      false,
                    pressingE:      false,
                    pressingR:      false,
                    pressingSHIFT:  false,
                    pressingSPACE:  false
                }
            };
            self.updatePosition = function(){
                if(self.controls.pressingUp){
                    self.position.y -= self.speed / settings.cps;
                    if(self.position.y < 0){
                        self.position.y = 0;
                    }
                }
                if(self.controls.pressingDown){
                    self.position.y += self.speed / settings.cps;
                    if(self.position.y > 9999){
                        self.position.y = 9999;
                    }
                }
                if(self.controls.pressingLeft){
                    self.position.x -= self.speed / settings.cps;
                    if(self.position.x < 0){
                        self.position.x = 0;
                    }
                }
                if(self.controls.pressingRight){
                    self.position.x += self.speed / settings.cps;
                    if(self.position.x > 9999){
                        self.position.x = 9999;
                    }
                }
            };
            
            PLAYER_LIST[self.id] = self;
            return self;
        };
        Player.update = function(){     
            var pack = [];
            for(var i in PLAYER_LIST){
                var player = PLAYER_LIST[PLAYER_LIST[i].id];
                
                player.updatePosition();
                
                pack.push({
                    id: player.id,
                    position: player.position,
                    angle: player.angle
                });
            }
            return pack;
        };
        
        
        //Spam Guard
        setInterval(() => {
            for(var id in SOCKET_LIST){
                if(SOCKET_LIST[id].spamGuard > 0){
                    SOCKET_LIST[id].spamGuard--;
                }
            }
        }, 3000);
        //Update LOBBIES
        setInterval(() => {
            //for(var L in LOBBY_LIST){
            //  var lobby = LOBBY_LIST[L];
                checkCPS();
                
                var pack = {
                    players: Player.update(),
                    server: {
                        cps: cpsSave
                    }
                };
                
                for(var S in SOCKET_LIST){
                    var user = SOCKET_LIST[SOCKET_LIST[S].id];
                    
                    user.emit('refresh', pack);
                }
            //}
        }, 1000/settings.cps);
        
        var map = [
            'Urban Delight',
            'Graveyard',
            'Farmlands'
        ];
        for(var i in map){
            var mapName = map[i];
            
            map[mapName] = {
                tileSize: 100,
                matrix: [],
            };
            for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
                map[mapName].matrix[j] = [];
                for(var k = 0; k < 100; k++){
                    map[mapName].matrix[j][k] = 0;
                }
            }
        }       
        function degrees_to_radians(degrees){
            var pi = Math.PI;
            return degrees * (pi/180);
        }
        function radians_to_degrees(radians){
            var pi = Math.PI;
            return radians / (pi/180);
        }
        var cps = 0,
            cpsCheck = 0,
            cpsSave = 0;
        function checkCPS(){
            cps++;
            var d = new Date().getSeconds();
            if(cpsCheck != d){
                cpsCheck = d;
                cpsSave = cps;
                cps = 0;
            }
        }
        console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started on port: ${port} | ${cpu.model}`);   
        clusterCount++;
    });
}
```

Comment: One issue I see is that you create a `setInterval()` timer when a user connects, but you NEVER stop that timer so with every new connection, you create yet another interval timer and after even just a few refreshes from one user (not to mention if there are lots of users), you'll have tons of interval timers all running.  In fact, that timer tries to still keep doing `socket.emit('updateLobbies', ...)` even long after the `socket` has disconnected.

Comment: You have to either share a single timer for all actively connected users or `clearInterval()` for a socket's specific timer every time a socket disconnects.

Comment: @jfriend00 good eye! I placed the `setInterva()l` for the `LOBBY_LIST` next to the other `setInterval()`s outside the connection, and emit using `io.sockets.emit`. Thank you for the help, but the problem persists :/

Comment: I do not understand what problem you're talking about.  What is supposed to run at 60cps?  And, what does the `angle` event have to do with any of this?

Comment: Under the `Update LOBBIES`, there is a `setInterval()` that updates the `players` information, which is supposed to run @ `1000/60ms` or 60cps (cycles per second -- or Idk what the proper term is). But it's working at half speed, @ 34cps. Only when the `socket.on('angle')` is triggered from the client side using `socket.emit('angle')`, the `setInterval()` then starts behaving normally, and cycles close to 60cps. It's weird, Idk :(

Comment: So, you're saying that a client is only receiving the `refresh` event (sent from the Update LOBBIES setInterval()) at 34cps until the server receives an `angle` event and then it goes to 60cps?  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: What is the purpose of `checkCPS()`?  What is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: Have you tried running this with only one cluster or no clustering at all just to make sure there isn't something in the clustering that is messing things up.  Socket.io clients with clustering need to either be forcing webSocket transport (so they don't use socket.io's multiple https requests at the start of the connection) or they need to be using some sort of server load balancing stickiness, otherwise they have startup connection issues where they spin up a bunch of connections before one finally takes.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it!

The purpose of `checkCPS()` is to record how many cycles the `setInterval()` runs within a second, I sent it to the client for the purpose of checking out how many times the setInterval fires within a second

I will try to remove the clustering to check that now

Comment: I commented out the clustering code so it only runs 1 server. Same issue

Comment: Well, I don't think `checkCPS()` is doing what you think it is doing, at least not very accurately as this is a very crude way to measure.  Much, much better to see how much time elapses (using the ms timer) for N cycles.  The larger a value of N you measure over, the more accurate your measurement will be.  If this is what you're claiming goes from 34 to 60, I'd first suspect bad measurement.

Comment: I've used the same code for other applications with no issues. It's always worked precise for me, even though I'm sure there is a better way of checking. Even so, I can see/feel the updating speed in my game. When the player is moving, it's not smooth. When I move my mouse (which triggers the `socket.emit('angle')` the player's movement smooths out

Comment: Are you using timers in the client?  Is the browser tab you're running this in always in the foreground (front-most tab in the browser with the browser the front-most app)?  I ask because browsers will slow down client-side timers when windows are no longer foreground or when they deem to save power, but actively using the mouse in a window tells the browser to give you full speed.

Comment: It may be we need to see client-side code.

Comment: Didn't allow me to post full code, so I put in snippets which I think are most relevant. --I very much appreciate the time you're putting on helping me

Comment: Also, I don't think it's the client side, as when I `console.log()` out the `checkCPS`, it still gives me 34-37cps, even when there are no clients connected

Comment: Any chance there is some sort of error or bad code path or expensive code path happening on the server before the client sends you an `angle`?  Are you sure you like the initial, default value for `player.angle`?

Comment: I just stripped the entire server code and just left `setInterval()` and `checkCPS`. I'm getting the same thing! Wth?!

Comment: I literally just have the `app.listen`, `setInterval(() => { checkCPS();}, 16.67);` along with the `function checkCPS()` (all in all, 40 lines of code) and I'm getting 37cps... is this some sort of hardware issue?

Comment: In my copy of node v14.13.0 running on my laptop, I don't get more than 42cps with a timer interval of 16.  When I reduce the timer interval to 10, I can get up to 56, but it won't go much higher than that.  So, I guess this is just the limits of the overhead of both your `calcCPS()` function and the event loop for recurring timers.  And, you have other interval timers running too.